# Why does conditional include stop working in Jekyll unless I add non-white space character(s)?

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid, github-pages

My Jekyll-based web site suddenly stopped including the Google Analytics script block. Yesterday, it was working (the script block was on all pages), but today, after I uploaded a new post, the script block was uniformly gone from all pages.

I'm hosting my site on GitHub pages, so in order to troubleshoot, I wanted to reproduce the issue on my local machine. It turned out that I was running old versions of Ruby and Jekyll on my local machine, so I updated Ruby and installed the [GitHub Pages Gem](https://github.com/github/pages-gem) in order to ensure that my local environment matched GitHub pages:

> gem install github-pages

That enabled me to reproduce the issue. Now, even when I ran

> jekyll serve --safe

the Analytics script block wasn't included in any page.

After *much* troubleshooting, I finally figured out that if I put any sort of **non-white space** character(s) in my JB/analytics file, between the *google* case and the include directive, it worked.

Thus, **this works**, in the sense that when the `--safe` switch is on, the script block in `JB/analytics-providers/google` is *included*:

```
{% case site.JB.analytics.provider %}
{% when "google" %}.
  {% include JB/analytics-providers/google %}
```

(notice the **period character** after `{% when "google" %}`).

However, **this doesn't work** - even with the `--safe` switch, the contents of `include JB/analytics-providers/google` is *never* included:

```
{% case site.JB.analytics.provider %}
{% when "google" %}
  {% include JB/analytics-providers/google %}
```

While I have a workaround, I'd much appreciate an explanation of this behaviour.

Comment: Funny stuff... looks like a bug in Liquid? http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-basics/logic#case

Comment: Are you possibly on Windows?  I run into all sorts encoding issues, including `\r\n` vs `\n`.  I now use a dedicated Debian VM for publishing and use Windows for design and posting. Ill even write some posts in the VM.

Comment: Yes, I'm on Windows, but I'm pretty sure GitHub pages aren't...

Comment: Fascinating.  Can you create a repo with a degenerate case showing this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

This would indeed be an issue with liquid. But I can't reproduce it with the version of liquid that is current for github pages, 2.5.5 ...

## Reproducing

This is what I tried, in a pry session:

```
# Load liquid 2.5.5
require 'liquid'

# Set up local file system to allow for includes
Liquid::Template.file_system = Liquid::LocalFileSystem.new( './' )

# Create template string
c = "{% case provider %}\n  {% when 'google' %}\n    {% include 'test' %}\n{% else %}\n  else\n{% endcase %}"

# Create template
t = Liquid::Template.parse c

# Render
t.render( { 'provider' => 'google' } )
```

Regardless of if I used `\n` or `\r\n` line endings I get the expected behaviour ( `=> "\n    Liquid error: No such template 'test'\n"` in this case since I didn't have a template, but it's calling the include so ... ).

Giving any other value than `'google'` triggers the else case and results in `=> "\n    else\n"`.

The addition of the period only affects the output by including the dot, not by if it triggers the include or not.

## Followup

Could you check your versions? `gem list liquid` and `gem list jekyll`

Could you copy your site and strip it down to a minimal example for us to play with? It's difficult to reproduce what you got with the information given.

### Note for experimenters

When executing Liquid in the console or from a test file remember that it likes it's hashes to be strings, not symbols. Feeding `{ provider: 'google' }` to render above results in `=> ""` ... It won't find your keys if they aren't strings.